# Can one add custom third-party logging Handler to finagle?

Tags: scala, logging, sentry, finagle

I was fairly surprised to discover, there is no (or rather I cannot find?) good way to do it:
`com.twitter.logging.Logging` has a nice method `handlers`, that seems to be intended exactly for this purpose, however, it is supposed to return a `List[com.twitter.loggin.Handler]`, and this `Handler` is not even a trait, but an abstract class.

So, if I need to integrate with, for example, `SentryHandler`, what are my options? The only thing I can think of is to hook into `premain` and shove my handler into the root logger (no, I am not considering implementing *another* ProxyHandler). It works, just seems kinda ... wrong?

Am I missing something?